# Error After upload in cpanel laravel8 image intervention Can't write image data to path

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-8

I'm using laravel 8 and I used the image intervention package. when I run my code on the local computer everything working fine but then I upload my project to my live server, I cant upload any image and also I can't delete image from live server. when I try to upload an image it says

**Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException
Can't write image data to path (image/slider/1707354763626883.png)**

and the code for uploading an image

```
public function StoreSlider(Request $request){

 $slider_image = $request->file('image');

// with the image intervation packge

 $name_gen= hexdec(uniqid()).'.'.$slider_image->getClientOriginalExtension();

image::make($slider_image)->resize(1920,1088)->save('image/slider/'.$name_gen);

$last_img ='image/slider/'.$name_gen;

 // insert information in database

Slider::insert([

'title'=> $request->title,

'description'=> $request->descriptison,

'image'=> $last_img,

'created_at'=> Carbon::now()

 ]);
```

Comment: It's all about permissions check permissions of the directory you want to upload file to it.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel need permissions to write on storage folder image/slider this should exist on your storage folder.

Check if this folder have the permisions to write:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R storage
```

Comment: Where do we run this code I have the same problem and I run it to my local project but a got 'No such file or directory'